# Detect Desktop Browser (not mobile) with Javascript

Tags: javascript, mobile

I found the following code to detect a desktop browser. But the method also detects some mobile browsers. How can I detect only desktop browsers like Safari, IE, Firefox, Opera etc?

```
is_desktopBrowser : function() {
    var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();

    var rwebkit = /(webkit)[ \/]([\w.]+)/;
    var ropera = /(opera)(?:.*version)?[ \/]([\w.]+)/;
    var rmsie = /(msie) ([\w.]+)/;
    var rmozilla = /(mozilla)(?:.*? rv:([\w.]+))?/;

    var match = rwebkit.exec(ua) ||
            ropera.exec(ua) ||
            rmsie.exec(ua) ||
            ua.indexOf("compatible") < 0 && rmozilla.exec(ua) ||
            [];

    return { browser: match[1] || "", version: match[2] || "0" };
},
```

Comment: Use the search feature on Stack overflow. For each browser you're trying to detect, there're several answer already.

Comment: Just a double check here, you're doing this because you can't detect a certain feature?

Comment: Browser detection is the devil, don't ever do it.

Comment: @Raynos There are reasons,,, for example advertising a desktop browser extensions (my case)

Comment: @Raynos User-Agent sniffing is the real devil.  Definitely don't do that on the client side when you have many other tools at your disposal, such as testing for the existence of certain functions/mehtods (i.e. feature detection - which may amount to browser detection, but is much more robust and future-proof).

Comment: @DavidCallanan Might your browser extensions be available for more than one browser - e.g. Edge and Chrome are both now Chromium-based, as is almost every other browser apart from Firefox - and is there a more accurate way of detecting that?

Comment: @Jake That's a good point. It would be nice if browsers which supported an extension API would expose some way of checking this. (e.g. `window.supportsChromiumExtensionStandard` etc.)

Answer (score 30):

<s>jQuery.browser can be helpful when trying to figure out which browser.</s> **`jQuery.browser` was removed in jQuery 1.9.**

I believe it is based on navigator.UserAgent, however navigator.UserAgent can tell you the OS on its own if you want.

Try this:

```
var isMobile = navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad)|(iPhone)|(iPod)|(android)|(webOS)/i)
```

[source](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/navigator.shtml)

Comment: `jQuery.browser` is deprecated in jQuery. Can't use it anymore.

Comment: @DaanHeskes There's good reason for this, browser UA detecting that jQuery.browser is doing is a bad idea because years from now everyone that is using FirefoxOS, Ubuntuphone, blackberry/blueberryphone, MSEdgeTablet10.5, supernewphone1.0, or whatever other devices are popular, will not be detected. If you want to do something on smaller screen mobile devices, by all means do so... without detecting each possible OS individually! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen

Answer (score 20):

I check for

```
('ontouchstart' in window)
```

since that will tell me if I'm on a touch capable device. Of course that also returns true for an ipad, which might not be considered a "mobile device", but then I just check `window.width` for layout purposes.

Comment: This approach returns false positive for touch-enabled desktops such as Microsoft's Surface and numerous other notebooks with Windows 8.

Comment: I tried the same in the latest Chrome and according to this, my desktop Chrome is a mobile, so it's a no.

Comment: @LajosMeszaros It returns `false` under desktop Chrome on Windows.

Comment: ('ontouchstart' in window ||
  navigator.maxTouchPoints > 0 ||
  navigator.msMaxTouchPoints > 0) for touch-enabled desktops such as Microsoft's Surface and numerous other notebooks with Windows 8

Answer (score 12):

I came up with this:

```
    var isTouchDevice = function() {  return 'ontouchstart' in window || 'onmsgesturechange' in window; };
    var isDesktop = window.screenX != 0 && !isTouchDevice() ? true : false;
```

It leverages two things we can hold on to. One, window.screenX will ALWAYS be 0 on any tablet / mobile device. You can't move windows on these devices, it is always full screen.

Two, isTouchDevice is a pretty reliable way to know if it's mobile (android / iphone tablet) or Windows Surfacey thing. It has a touch event. Combining the two gives us a high degree of certainty that it's a mobile or tablet. If you're not one of those, you must be desktop.

Yes, you might have a desktop that somehow reports itself as touch and has the browser maxxed to the upper left. In my case, I can let that go.

Comment: You should have window.screenX === 0 in the isTouchDevice check, rather than the other way around. window.screenX can be 0 on a desktop.

Comment: Not a reliable option imo. There are laptops with touch screens.

Comment: Mark this is true. But in some cases, it is close enough given the brevity of the code. There are cases where the outcome, although not ideal - is still usable for most and the code is compact enough to warrant value.

Comment: I thought I would add some input here as well (although an old answer). Some tablets will allow you to move windows, such as the Surface Pro. Just keep this in mind when coding your next project.

Comment: It's true David, and this code could be tweaked a bit to add detection for surface as an outlier. Most touch devices have no window movement, thus the screenX is a pretty good call. Depends on the use case.

Comment: `window.screenX != 0 && !isTouchDevice() ? true : false;` You can write this shorter as `window.screenX != 0 && !isTouchDevice();`

Answer (score 7):

I have been investigating this for my ReView (Responsive Viewport) project. I use a combination of the following.

- window.screenX

Most mobile browsers have the 'window' locked to the left hand side. So if this isn't zero, likely to be a desktop browser window.

- window.devicePixelRatio and screen.width

If dpr is 1 and screen width is reported as large via screen.width, likely to be desktop.

- window.orientation

It is rare to find a desktop monitor in portrait mode. However, this could happen.

More unlikely is multiple orientation changes while using your site/app. This implies a desktop user would be spinning their screen... very unlikely.

A combination of these with some common sense and you can achieve a pretty solid guess.

The project mentioned along with more info is at http://responsiveviewport.com

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can go to http://detectmobilebrowsers.com and generate a JS script which will detect whether a browser is a mobile browser.
Unless you are worried about Smart TVs or some other non mobile nor desktop appliances, you can use that script and assume that if the browser is NOT a mobile browser then it should be a desktop browser.

Here is an example solution using the regex-es generated by that site:

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isDesktop = !(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(ua.substr(0,4)));
```

Comment: Your answer is the best one in the post, but I leave a downvote because this code has a syntax error, you declare `ua` but in the regex use an `a` variable that is not defined. fix it, then I will change the downvote to an upvote.

Comment: Geez. Look at the hall monitor.

Comment: @AmerllicA I've fixed that typo, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: I copy/pasted this and my console says : "Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined" ?

Answer (score 2):

Even it's a bit overkill for your case, [**express-useragent**](https://github.com/biggora/express-useragent) is one of the best solution as it can be used on both server and browser. Your case:

**Include js file in HTML**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/express-useragent.js"></script>
```

**Execute the plugin**

```
var userAgent = new UserAgent().parse(navigator.userAgent);
```

**Value of `userAgent` will be something like**

```
{
  "isMobile":false,
  "isDesktop":true,
  "isBot":false,
  .....
  "browser":"Chrome",
  "version":"17.0.963.79",
  "os":"Windows 7",
  "platform":"Microsoft Windows",
  "source":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.79..."
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it is easy to detect mobile or tablet device, then with a simple result inversion we can understand that is desktop or not, for easy accessing I write a simple function:

```js
const isDesktop = () => {
  const navigatorAgent =
    navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;
  return !(
    /(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series([46])0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino|android|ipad|playbook|silk/i.test(
      navigatorAgent
    ) ||
    /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br([ev])w|bumb|bw-([nu])|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc-s|devi|dica|dmob|do([cp])o|ds(12|-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly([-_])|g1 u|g560|gene|gf-5|g-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd-([mpt])|hei-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs-c|ht(c([- _agpst])|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac([ \-/])|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja([tv])a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt([ /])|klon|kpt |kwc-|kyo([ck])|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/([klu])|50|54|-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t([- ov])|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30([02])|n50([025])|n7(0([01])|10)|ne(([cm])-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok([6i])|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan([adt])|pdxg|pg(13|-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt-g|qa-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|-[2-7]|i-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h-|oo|p-)|sdk\/|se(c([-01])|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh-|shar|sie([-m])|sk-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h-|v-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl-|tdg-|tel([im])|tim-|t-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m-|m3|m5)|tx-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c([- ])|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas-|your|zeto|zte-/i.test(
      navigatorAgent.substr(0, 4)
    )
  );
};
```

**Note**: this function is based on **ES6** and it should transpile, best case for **ReactJS**.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your script is, that it's just trying to detect the browser with the `UserAgent`-string which is not quite accurate because everyone can fake his `UserAgent`.

For a pretty good read on browser detection, check out this link: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html

Comment: But obviously if a user is going to mess with their user agent, then they can expect weird behavior, no?

Answer (score 1):

Simply include [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) js file it adds the classes called no-touch to all desktop browsers so you can easily target using these classes

Comment: Does that really work because I heard that was impossible from js - http://www.stucox.com/blog/you-cant-detect-a-touchscreen/

Comment: Well, some desktops have touch screens.

Comment: Actually, many (if not most) current Windows laptops have touch screens nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

What is the specific feature of a desktop browser that means you want different behaviour?

Is it the input mechanism (mouse and physical keyboard vs touch and virtual keyboard), the larger screen size, or something else?

For example, in CSS4 you can use [`@media (any-pointer: coarse)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/any-pointer) for touch-enabled devices and [`@media (pointer: coarse)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/pointer) for devices where the primary input is touch (i.e. phones and tablets whether or not an external keyboard is plugged in).  CSS4 is mostly fully supported by modern browsers.

In JavaScript, you can use [`Window.matchMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) to test for any CSS media query (including those above) as suggested in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47472607/2511031).