# How to hidden modal dialog box

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I have try use dialog message. My question, how to hidden it/ its not see anything?
My destination is to create media query when desktop its hide and other media showing so I need code for hide in css/html file. 
My code: `style="display:none;"` but fail.

My code on fiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/debudi/fqaWF/1/)

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean hide? hide the dialog? just close it if u wanna hide it.

Comment: My destination is to create media query when desktop its hide and other media showing so I need code for hide in css/html file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [close method](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-close) as the api mention

```
$(#dialog-message ).dialog( "close" );
```

the above will work after a dialog is showed. But if don't want to show the dialog at the time the page is loaded just use the `autoOpen` option

```
$(function() {
$( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
buttons: {
Ok: function() {
$( this ).dialog( "close" );
}
}
});
});
```

Comment: but my media query didn't work. I want to hide only on desktop so I need to hide use css or html file

Comment: My destination is to create media query when desktop its hide and other media showing so I need code for hide in css/html file. If you edit on javascript, my media query will not working. Thanks

Comment: i think it should be done by javascript manually , please refer [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7995752/1599694) to know how to do it

Comment: could you please to modify your fiddle because css media query its different with js media query. Thank you

Comment: why didn't work on my desktop. can use media query(max width, min width)

Answer (score 0):

You have to do

```
$( "#dialog-message" ).dialog( "close" );
```

[**WORKING FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/fqaWF/2/)

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
$(function() {
$( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
modal: true,
buttons: {
Ok: function() {
$( this ).dialog( "close" );
}
}
});
$('.ui-dialog').css('display','none');
});
```

if i've understand you necessity ...

Comment: but my media query didn't work. I want to hide only on desktop so I need to hide use css or html file.

Answer (score 0):

In the bootstrap 4,

```
// hiding the model,       
$('#myModal').modal('hide');
```