# Detecting if you are on a desktop

Tags: javascript, mobile

I'm building an app for touch screens and has a on screen keyboard for them to use. This works wonders for the desktop computers, however not so much for the mobile devices that have the built in keyboards.

I have been looking around to see if there is a way to detect if you are on desktop or mobile, but everything I have seen has been deprecated. Is there any way to do so? So I can only enable the library if you are on a desktop computer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-jquery or you can use `if (screen.width <= 699)`

Comment: @CanerAkdeniz, $browser has been deprecated and I can't use screen size because I don't know what devices they'll be using. It could be anything, we have no control over that. Plus the desktop screens are actually quite small and I need it to init on those.

Comment: `navigator.userAgent` is not jquery and does not use `.browser()`, so you can still use it. check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/mnbw23gg/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect Desktop Browser (not mobile) with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7995752/detect-desktop-browser-not-mobile-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

you can accomplish this by doing:

```
if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){
    //your code for mobile devices
}
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mnbw23gg/

Comment: This doesn't account for scaling though. You'd have to update every time a new mobile platform is introduced

Answer (score 1):

For your case, you should detect all kind of mobile or tablets to find out it is a desktop or a touch device. I refer you to see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61073480/6877799) but you can also use the below function to detect your running area is desktop or not:

```js
function isDesktop() {
  var navigatorAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;
  return !(
    /(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series([46])0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino|android|ipad|playbook|silk/i.test(
      navigatorAgent
    ) ||
    /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br([ev])w|bumb|bw-([nu])|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc-s|devi|dica|dmob|do([cp])o|ds(12|-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly([-_])|g1 u|g560|gene|gf-5|g-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd-([mpt])|hei-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs-c|ht(c([- _agpst])|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac([ \-/])|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja([tv])a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt([ /])|klon|kpt |kwc-|kyo([ck])|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/([klu])|50|54|-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t([- ov])|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30([02])|n50([025])|n7(0([01])|10)|ne(([cm])-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok([6i])|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan([adt])|pdxg|pg(13|-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt-g|qa-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|-[2-7]|i-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h-|oo|p-)|sdk\/|se(c([-01])|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh-|shar|sie([-m])|sk-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h-|v-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl-|tdg-|tel([im])|tim-|t-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m-|m3|m5)|tx-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c([- ])|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas-|your|zeto|zte-/i.test(
      navigatorAgent.substr(0, 4)
    )
  );
};
```