# How to detect if pointer coarse or fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, interaction-media-features

I read this about interaction media which is explain how css can detect if pointer is touchscreen or not. It's using `@media` query like

```
@media (pointer: coarse){
  body{
    // do something
  }
}
```

but I just wonder how to implementing it using javascript ot JQuery, is it possible?

Thank you, and sorry for my English

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
is_fine = matchMedia('(pointer:fine)').matches
is_coarse = matchMedia('(pointer:coarse)').matches
```

Works in Chrome for me.

Comment: Alternatively you can style some element with CSS and check whether that style is applied via JS.

Comment: `window.matchMedia()` should be well supported: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia – basically if the CSS method works, the `matchMedia()` should also work.

Comment: Would be nice if there was a more native JavaScript API for determining input devices, without having to go via ` matchMedia`, but I could not find one.